# publish a golang based binary on github to be installed with "go get"

Tags: go

I created a simple lazy package manager for go.
I published it at https://github.com/kfirufk/glpm.

when I execute `go get github.com/kfirufk/glpm` I get no errors, but it compiles it as a module since the resulted pkg content at `$GOPATH/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/kfirufk`is `glpm.a`.

I want it to be compiled as an executable. what am I missing?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your project building as an executable, you need to have:

- All of the buildable Go files as part of the package `main`, and
- Define a `main` function to be the entry point for your program

However, if your package can also be used as a library, a common pattern is to have your executable stored in `$PACKAGE/cmd/$EXECUTABLE_NAME`. This would mean your package executable would be fetched using:

```
go get -u github.com/kfirufk/glpm/cmd/glpm
```